# Start with a circular cake...

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics

This is a random math question I saw and it piqued my interest. I like cake.

Start with a circular cake and cut it with five straight slices. What is the largest number of pieces that you can create if you do not move pieces between cuts?

I feel like this puzzle is tricking me,

I started by

Cutting the cake in half. 
Cutting it again into quarters. 
Lining up the quarters in a row and cut all the way down (now 1/8ths) 
Lining them up again in a row and cut all the way down (1/16ths) 
Then finishing with another cut, I got 16 pieces... but this seems too simple.

Any suggestions? How did you solve this puzzle?

Comment: Your procedure involved moving pieces.

Comment: [Lazy caterer's sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_caterer%27s_sequence) for 2-dimensional cakes/pizzas. The 3-dimensional version is known as the [cake number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cake_number).

Comment: The cake is a lie.

Comment: Will pancakes do, or does the solution have to hold for more general cakes?